# Difference of DLL and LIB extension

Tags: dll

I know that LIB files are static link - when I use it in my project, on compiling, all it's content added to my file. DLL is dynamic - loaded to memory and all the projects that needs it, can use it.

Why should I use DLL instead of LIB (and vice versa?
How can I compile my code to DLL (or LIB)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library), `.lib` files are used in conjunction with `.dll`, which means that you don't have to prefer one over another.

> For example, kernel32.dll, the primary dynamic library for Windows'
>   base functions such as file creation and memory management, is linked
>   via kernel32.lib.